# Changing cell background on user edit automatically - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a script that automatically change the background color of cells depending on which user edits it. I currently have this code but it doesn't do anything. We need to know which user edits or creates a new entry.

I just need the cells in the first column to change background color. This is for a Data base I'm working with 4 other people

```
function checkEdits() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") { 
        var r = s.getActiveCell();

        //checks the column
        if (r.getColumn() == 1) {
            var email = r.Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

            if (email == "XXXXX@gmail.com") {
                r.setBackground('#dbbf94');
            }

            if (mail == "YYYYYY@gmail.com") {
                r.setBackground('#94dbab');
            }

            if (mail == "ZZZZZZ@gmail.com") {
                r.setBackground('#a2bfdf');
            }

            if (mail == "MMMMMMMM@gmail.com") {
                r.setBackground('#cf9ce5');
            }

            if (mail == "NNNNNNN@gmail.com") {
                r.setBackground('#dfa2b1');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when a user edit a cell un Column A, the same cell changes its background to the specific user color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this. If parts aren't clear, let me know, I'll give you more details.

```js
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getSheetId() && e.range.getColumn() == 1.0){
    switch (e.user){
      case "XXXXX@gmail.com":
        e.range.setBackground('#dbbf94');
        break;
      case "YYYYYY@gmail.com":
        e.range.setBackground('#94dbab');
        break;
      case "ZZZZZZ@gmail.com":
        e.range.setBackground('#a2bfdf');
        break;
      case "MMMMMMMM@gmail.com":
        e.range.setBackground('#cf9ce5');
        break;
      case "NNNNNNN@gmail.com":
        e.range.setBackground('#dfa2b1');
        break;
      default:
        e.range.setBackground('white');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a much cleaner way to write it. I'm really new at this. Thanks for your help. The only problem is a "cannot read property"range"" error when I try to run it. Do you know why is that?

Comment: it says is in line 2

Comment: just to be clear, this function doesn't need (can't) be run as a standalone function, it will automatically run when a change is made to your sheet. So you rather need to make changes to the first column of "Sheet1" and see the color change.

Comment: thanks man. You helped me a lot. I manage to make it work somehow