# Google sheets - How can a script recognize the sheet users?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a script that should change the background color of a cell depending on which user inputs data. It seems the script does not recognize other users but me (the sheet owner), so when someone else inputs data the cell changes color but only to the one designated to my user.

I've tried a switch statement but nothing happened, so I used if and else if statements and at least got the cells to change colors. I program another cell to show the user name to check who is editing data, but only my username appears, other just don't show up.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var cell = s.getActiveCell();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
    if(cell.getColumn() == 2 ) {
      var colorCell = cell.offset(0,-1);
      var conCell = cell.offset(0,13); //Confirmation cell to see the user name
      conCell.setValue(user);
      var dateCell = cell.offset(0, 12); //this bit is to register the date of the edit
      if( dateCell.getValue() === '' ){ 
        dateCell.setValue(new Date());}
      if (user = "xxxx@gmail.com"){//only this user name seems to be recognized
        colorCell.setBackground('#dbbf94');
             }
      else if (user = "zzzz@gmail.com"){
        colorCell.setBackground('#94dbab');
      }
      else if (user = "yyyyy@gmail.com"){
        colorCell.setBackground('#cf9ce5');
      }
  }
}
}
```

I want the background color to be specific for each user

Comment: I've been messing around with the code and change the order of the user and the color changed. That means The code is executing just until the first if statement related to background color. Has anyone any idea of why could that be?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57577388/5851272 ?